# Validators do not work as they should. Django

Tags: django, forms

I am trying to add a validator in accordance with the Django documentation to my field but I can not get the effect, every time i can sent e-mail even though there is no "fred@example.com" in the field.

Do I have to add any additional lines of code in the view? any help will be appreciated.

```
class EmailContactForm(forms.Form):
    e_mail = forms.EmailField()
    tresc_wiadomosci = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def clean_recipients(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['e_mail']
        if "fred@example.com" not in data:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You have forgotten about Fred!")
```

Answer (score 2):

change `clean_recipients` to `clean_e_mail`

```
class EmailContactForm(forms.Form):
e_mail = forms.EmailField()
tresc_wiadomosci = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

def clean_e_mail(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['e_mail']
    if "fred@example.com" not in data:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You have forgotten about Fred!")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override the `clean` method of a form, you need to give it the same name as the field it cleans. In this case, you should name your method `clean_e_mail`.